# Replace all special characters like 'é' in URL with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, url, character-encoding, escaping

I'm receiving response from an API that contains name strings with special letters like `'é'`.

Then I need to make a request to another API with query string containing this name with `'é'`. API is third-party service which doesn't understand this letters.

`encodeURIComponent` doesn't help, server still returns an error.

I would like to replace special characters with existing alternatives like `'é'=>'e'`, is there a library or some ready solution for this purpose?

Comment: This question may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7772553/javascript-unicode-normalization

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those characters are called *diacritic* (more specifically this tiny stroke above the `e`).

Here's a JS lib https://github.com/superjoe30/diacritics

You need to modify it slightly in order to use it without any module loader.

Just replace `exports.remove` with sth. like `window.removeDiacrits` and then

```
str = removeDiacrits(str);
```

and it's probably a good idea to wrap the code in a [IIFE](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/).

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried the `encodeURI`

`encodeURI` - To encode an URL

`encodeURIComponent` - to encode the query string parameter