# Javascript Unicode: same letters but different unicode

Tags: javascript, unicode, keyboard-layout

I've got to send text to a printservice, which only accepts certain types of special characters, i.e. ï. My client somehow inputs text in such a way that the letters look the same, but have a different underlying unicode symbol, and are thereby not processed correctly by the printservice. Example:

```
Mine: ï (unicode \u00EF)
Theirs: ï (unicode \u0069\u0308), copy pasting the 2 symbols in chrome bar for example, will show that it actually looks the same in textarea's)
```

How can I convert all special characters from "their style" to "my style" (dutch keyboard layout on Windows)? I guess this has something to do with OS or keyboard layouts, but I cannot find a list stating the differences, or anything related to this issue. Does someone has a suggestion how to proceed?

Comment: They are both valid. Accented characters can be done via compositing two characters and many also have a dedicated character. Sounds like a bug that the printservice cannot process certain types of valid Unicode.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. It is a bug in the printservice indeed, but it's outside my area to change that code. Is there a (simple) way I can convert all the compositions to a single dedicated character?

Comment: As current answers highlight, I think you mistyped sample data when composing the question. [U+0308](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0308/index.htm) is just the diaeresis (and, of course, [U+0020](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0020/index.htm) is good old white space).

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario I corrected the Question’s Unicode code point numbers per Answer by Kevin Hakanson.

Comment: "all the compositions to a single dedicated character"—this concept can only apply to situations where Unicode has a dedicated character. There is no restriction on the base characters to which a combining character can be applied and no limit on the sequence of combining characters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As correctly pointed out in the comments, there are two ways (or "normalization forms") to represent accented characters in unicode:

- with a dedicated symbol (`\u00EF == ï`)
- with a composition of the basic letter + accent (i.e. `i + ¨ == i + \u0308 == ï`)

ES6 adds a dedicated function, which converts strings between normalization forms : [`String.normalize`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/normalize).

```
// convert one-char ("composed") to multiple-chars ("decomposed") form:
escape("\u00EF".normalize("NFD"))  
> "i%u0308"

// convert decomposed form to composed:
escape("i\u0308".normalize("NFC"))  
> "%EF"
```

If your system doesn't support `normalize` yet, look around for shims.

Answer (score 4):

[\u00EF](http://unicode-table.com/en/#00EF) is ï or the **Latin Small Letter I with Diaeresis** (and \u0020 is the **Space** character)

[\u0069](http://unicode-table.com/en/#0069)[\u0308](http://unicode-table.com/en/#0308) is the **Latin Small Letter I** followed by the **Combining Diaeresis**

[Normalization](http://unicode.org/faq/normalization.html) is needed to transform the second, two-character sequence into the first. You will need to find some utility to perform this normalization before you send to your print service.

See [JavaScript Unicode normalization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7772553/javascript-unicode-normalization) for some options.