# Unicode: How to obtain all code points for a character like e.g. ã (so it can be used in JavaScript regex)?

Tags: javascript, regex, unicode

My Unicode-related vocabulary isn't very good, so sorry for the verbose question.

A character like `ã` can be represented by `\u00e3` (Latin small letter a with tilde), or `\u0061` (Latin small letter a) in combination with combining diacritical mark `\u0303` (combining tilde). Now, in Java, in order to match any Unicode letter, I'd look for `[\p{L}]`, but JavaScript doesn't understand that, so I'll have to look for the individual code points (`\unnnn`). How can I start with an ã and figure out all the various ways it can be represented in Unicode so I can include them in my regular expression in `\unnnn` format?

Comment: Your original question probably fell afoul the *"Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow"* rule. I've edited it to try to implement the second half of that close reason (*"Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."*) as best I can

Comment: You might want to change the focus of the question, though, because I think you're hitting the X/Y problem: You've asked a question about X ("how do I get the list of Unicode ways to represent ã so I can include them in a regex in `\unnnn` form) , but your *real* question is Y ("How do I reliably detect ã in a JS regular expression whether it's written `\u00e3` or `\u0061\u0303`)?"

Comment: Very interesting question.

Comment: You are asking two questions. One is "How can I do stuff like `\p{L}`; the other is "how do I decompose a Unicode character?" The first question is discussed [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/280712/javascript-unicode-regexes); the second [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7772553/javascript-unicode-normalization).

Comment: Thanks. @raymond-chen: I really want to know how to get it decomposed and printed to screen, I guess... Which seems to be the answer to the first question, if I'm not mistaken...

Comment: Decomposition was your second question. The first was generalized character classes.

Answer (score 2):

> How can I start with an ã and figure out all the various ways it can be represented in Unicode

You're looking for the [Unicode Equivalence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_equivalence).

The 2 forms you mentioned are the `composed form`, and the `decomposed form`. To get [cannonically equivalent](http://unicode.org/faq/normalization.html) Unicode forms, you could use [`String.prototype.normalize()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/normalize).

- **Important:** Check the [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/normalize#Browser_compatibility) for Browser Compatibility.

---

`str.normalize([form])` accepts the following forms:

- NFC — Normalization Form Canonical Composition.
- NFD — Normalization Form Canonical Decomposition.
- NFKC — Normalization Form Compatibility Composition.
- NFKD — Normalization Form Compatibility Decomposition.

> Code point sequences that are defined as **canonically equivalent** are assumed to have the same appearance and meaning when printed or displayed.
>
> Sequences that are defined as **compatible** are assumed to have possibly distinct appearances, but the same meaning in some contexts.

*[Quote from Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_equivalence)*

-Choose the *equivalence form* you like.

---

For example, using the `Latin small letter a with tilde` in Compatibility Form:

```
var char = "ã";
var nfkc = char.normalize('NFKC');
var nfkd = char.normalize('NFKD');
```

```js
// Returns bytes as Unicode escaped sequences
function escapeUnicode(str){
    var i;
    var result = "";
    for( i = 0; i < str.length; ++i){
        var c = str.charCodeAt(i);
        c = c.toString(16).toUpperCase();
        while (c.length < 4) {
            c = "0" + c;
        }
        result += "\\u" + c;
    }
    return result;
}

var char = "ã";
var nfkc = char.normalize('NFKC');
var nfkd = char.normalize('NFKD');

document.write('<br />NFKC: ' + escapeUnicode(nfkc));
document.write('<br />NFKD: ' + escapeUnicode(nfkd));
```