# Swedish charactors not displaying correclty in Safari browser

Tags: javascript, reactjs, utf-8, safari

I am working on a react project which supports the Swedish language as well.
When I open the web app in the Chrome browse.

[image]

This is the expected behavior and this is correct.
But then I open the same link in the Safari web browser.

[image]

The top two dots for the letter a are not placed correctly.

index.html file contains this line also

```
<meta charset="utf-8" />
```

How do I fix this error?
Any help thanks in advance.

Comment: It's probably not the real character `ä`, but an `a` with umlaut diacritics added. Safari is known to have problems with those. Re-type the content and make sure it's an actual `ä`, and not something else copy&pasted from elsewhere.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JavaScript Unicode normalization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7772553/javascript-unicode-normalization) Read [When "Zoë" !== "Zoë". Or why you need to normalize Unicode strings](https://withblue.ink/2019/03/11/why-you-need-to-normalize-unicode-strings.html) as well…